# Check checkboxes are selected in a HTML form with JavaScript where I can only access them via getElementsByName()

Tags: javascript, html

In the HTML form I have these two check boxes for male and female...

```
<tr><td>
Gender:
</td><td> 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female
</td></tr>
```

I want to check to see if either of these values are checked.. Do I have to check each individual box with

```
document.getElementsByName("gender")[0].checked;
document.getElementsByName("gender")[1].checked;
```

Or is there a way I can get both of these values assigned to an array and then go through them with a for-each incase I need to add more options in the future? (I know I can't add more than male or female, but this is for future proofing myself with other checkbox options)

(I'm aware that I could add classnames to this to make it easier, but this is part of an assignment for University which I'm currently working through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way,

```
var arrRadio=document.getElementsByName("gender");
for(radio in arrRadio){
arrRadio[radio].checked=true;
}
```

or you could also access the radio button in this way in case it is present in a form with a name,

```
var form=document.myForm;
var arrRadio=form.gender;
/*or*/
var arrRadio=document.myForm.gender;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can add class names to the markup you could use *getElementsByClassName*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

(assuming you don't want to use jQuery).

Comment: Due to this being a university project I'm not allowed to alter the HTML, but I agree this would be an easier way if I wasn't bound to any criteria! Thanks :)

Comment: If you can use jQuery the following will get you all radio buttons: var $elements = $(':radio');

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line:

var x = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");

This will get you only the selected one.
You can add class to better get only radio buttons, like ".gender:checked"